# How large could a subterranean society be?

Tags: underground

In my fictional world, there is an entire society that lives underground in abandoned mineshafts and the like. In this subterranean 'realm' , there are countries and towns just like on the surface.

Would that be possible?

Would there be any problems? What about earthquakes?

Comment: Note that the duplicate is science based despite using the term "Dwarves". There are a number of other related questions you can see in the links to the right too ->